How to execute a Lua function after exiting insert mode in Neovim
Teach me please how to make Neovim execute a Lua function after exiting an insert mode.

Use an autocommand using the vim API:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("InsertLeave", {
  callback = function()
      print("Exited insert mode!");
  end
});

